# Get table name from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I used `ActiveRecord::Base.set_table_name` to set my table name on a dynamically created ActiveRecord class. Now I need to know how to get that value later. The api docs don't mention anything on how to do this. Also, I can't derive the table name off the ActiveRecord class name because they are keyed differently than the table name.

Here is a better example of what I am doing

```
table_klass = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.const_set(const_name,table_klass)
    app = @app
    table_klass.class_eval do
      after_save do
        @@channel.push self
      end
      set_table_name t.server_table
      establish_connection(
        :adapter  => "mysql2",
        :host     => app.db_host,
        :username => app.db_user,
        :password => app.db_pass,
        :database => app.db_name
      )
    end
```

In this case, if the `const_name` = Test  and the database name is Database it should create a class of ActiveRecord::Base::DatabaseTest, which it does. But when I call table_name on it I get undefined local variable or method. Do I need to call table_name on the class?

**Update:**
I got it working by calling `instance.class.table_name`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Have you tried `table_name`? [Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name).

Comment: I have tried this, it says undefined method. I should be a little clearer. I am metaprogramming the creation of this class. I am adding a clearer example to my question

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm a bit out of my depth with that much meta. All I can tell you is that `table_name` is a class method on `ActiveRecord::Base` (and hence its derived classes), gained from `ActiveRecord::ModelSchema::ClassMethods`.

Comment: Rails comes through with the principle of least astonishment once again.

Answer (score 19):

Late to the party.

I used the following rails code:

```
my_record = Record.id(0) # hypothetical code
table_name = my_record.class.table_name
```

Comment: why not just `Record.table_name` as other answers suggested? :thumbdown:

Answer (score 12):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

User.table_name 
# 'users'
```