# ActiveRecord class name as var

Tags: ruby, active-record-query

I want to use the ActiveRecord to manupulate my tables data, but what if my table name is variable. This code, will generate an error. Any suggestion?

```
name = "Posts"

class name < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: I guess you should look for metaprogramming solution which builds your class dynamicly.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/10334103/846163

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do something like the following:

```
name = 'Post' # Dynamically generate the class name
klass = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
          # This is the base class.
          # You can pass a block with new
          # methods here if you'd like.
        end
Object.const_set name, klass
name.constantize.new # Call your class dynamically :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to set the table_name from a variable:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name
    # Some method to determine and set the table name.
    # Must return a string with a table name. E.g. the 
    # following would set the table name to `posts_2015-11-15`

    "posts_#{Date.today}"
  end

  # ...
end
```